# Enum Error Code returns JSON

Tags: c#, enums

What I am using right now is

```
Response.StatusCode = 420;
Dictionary<string, object> error = new Dictionary<string, object>();
error.Add("ErrorCode", BL.Error.Error.NoMethod);
error.Add("ErrorMessage", BL.Error.Enumerations.GetEnumDesc(BL.Error.Error.NoMethod));
Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(error);
```

How I want to use is with same result.

```
Response.StatusCode = 420;
error = BL.Error.Error.NoMethod;
Response.Write(error);
```

How can I convert my code to this?
Thank you for your help.

My Error Classes

```
public enum Error
{
    [Description("No Method")]
    NoMethod = 1,
    [Description("Missing Value")]
    MissingValue = 2
}

public class Enumerations
{
    public static string GetEnumDesc(Enum value)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

    DescriptionAttribute[] attributes =
        (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(
        typeof(DescriptionAttribute),
        false);

    if (attributes != null &&
        attributes.Length > 0)
        return attributes[0].Description;
    else
        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create yourself an `Error` class, accept the enum value in the contructor and override its `ToString()` method to suit your desired output:

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        ...
    }
```